# How to iterate over Pandas dataframe row & create a dataframe in each iteration

Tags: python

I have a pandas data frame gmat. The sample data looks like

```
YEAR  student score mail_id      phone            Loc
2012  abc     630   abc@xyz.com  1-800-000-000   pqr
2012  pqr     630   pqr@xyz.com  1-800-000-000   abc
```

I would like to iterate through this data frame & create a dataframe from rows of this data frame in for loop & use that data frame for doing calculation.Each iteration in for loop will overwrite previous dataframe with the current row in iteration. For example my first data frame in for loop will look like

```
YEAR  student score mail_id      phone            Loc
2012  abc     630   abc@xyz.com  1-800-000-000   pqr
```

and second dataframe after overwriting first row will look like

```
YEAR  student score mail_id      phone            Loc
2012  pqr     630   pqr@xyz.com  1-800-000-000   abc
```

So I tried following code

```
for row in gmat.iterrows():
    
    df=pd.DataFrame(list(row))
```

But while checking I'm seeing df is not populated properly. It's only showing 2 columns
Can you please suggest me how to do it?

I also tried this based on Georgy's suggestion, I used `for index, row in gmat.iterrows()`. Here I'm getting row as a `pd.Series` then I'm using `gmrow=pd.DataFrame(row)` But my column heading of original data is coming as row. Data I'm getting as 

`YEAR    2012
student abc
score   630
mail_id abc@xyz.com
phone   1-800-000-000
Loc pqr`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: See the accepted answer above. It should be `for index, row in gmat.iterrows()`. In your case your `row` is a tuple of an integer index and a `pd.Series`. This is why you get those '2 columns'. Also, when you fix this, you won't need to convert `row` to `list`.

Comment: @Georgy,Please refer my original post. I' tried your suggestion but output format what I'm getting is different than what I want

Comment: `gmrow=pd.DataFrame(row).T` will transpose it to the format you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can slice your dataframe like this:

`for index, row in gmat.iterrows():
    x = df[index:index+1]
    print("print iterations:",x)`

`print` is just an example. You can do your desired transformations with `x`

Comment: There is no need to use `iterrows` if you never use the `row`. Simple `for index in range(...)` would be enough

Comment: Please could you elaborate use of range to iterate over a dataframe?

As far as I know, iterrows returns dataframe with its original schema. Range function will take int input and will possibly throw int object is not iterable error when used on a dataframe.

Comment: I don't really understand what is not clear. Yes, `iterrows` yields rows of a dataframe along with corresponding indices, but use of it is justified if you actually use those rows. In your case you are using only the indices. Either use `row` or don't use `iterrows` at all. So, for example, either `for _, row in df.iterrows(): print(pd.DataFrame(row).T)` or `for i in range(df.shape[0]): print(df[i:i+1])`

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the explaination sir!